# process.env is undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to separate development and production endpoints and to achieve that I decided to create two text files in src folder like .env.production and .env.development. Inside .env.production I have put: `REACT_APP_API_MESSENGER_CHAT = https://api.com/ REACT_APP_ENV = “prod”`

and in .env.development I have put: `REACT_APP_API_MESSENGER_CHAT = https://api.dev.com/ REACT_APP_ENV = “dev”`

Then, I try to access that variable like this: `process.env.REACT_APP_API_MESSENGER_CHAT` but it says that `REACT_APP_API_MESSENGER_CHAT is undefined`. Also, my package.json for npm run start looks: "start": "react-scripts start". Pls help

Comment: Are you using a library to load enviroment variables ? like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv ?

Answer (score 0):

Please move the `.env` file to the top of the project.

If your computer is macOS, please install `cross-env`.

Installation Method
`yarn add cross-env` or `npm install cross-env`

How to use

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts start",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src react-scripts build",
}
```

It may not be an accurate answer.
But I hope it helps you.